# How to use K-means with parquet file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means, parquet

i'd like to learn how to use K-Means algorithm on Spark.
I have a parquet file and i would like to analyze it with k-means. How can I tell spark to analyze only specific column? How can I remove null values from rows? Can someone write a simple code of how to do it?
Thank you

Comment: This is 4 questions in 1! :) Read parquet, run k-means, select only certain columns, and remove nulls... You should at least try first and then a more specific question if you get stuck anywhere

Answer (score 0):

If you want specific columns just do select on dataframe and then use *[VectorAssembler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler)*. KMeans require Vector column as input features.
You can delete, fill or replace null values using *[DataFrameNaFunctions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions)*.

See example below:

```
val dataset= spark.range(10)
  .select('id.cast("double").as("c1"),lit('id/2).as("c2").cast("double"))

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(dataset.columns)
  .setOutputCol("myFeatures")
val output = assembler.transform(dataset)

// Trains a k-means model.
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1L).setFeaturesCol("myFeatures")
val model = kmeans.fit(output)

// Make predictions
val predictions = model.transform(output)

predictions.show()

+---+---+----------+----------+
| c1| c2|myFeatures|prediction|
+---+---+----------+----------+
|0.0|0.0| (2,[],[])|         1|
|1.0|0.5| [1.0,0.5]|         1|
|2.0|1.0| [2.0,1.0]|         1|
|3.0|1.5| [3.0,1.5]|         1|
|4.0|2.0| [4.0,2.0]|         1|
|5.0|2.5| [5.0,2.5]|         0|
|6.0|3.0| [6.0,3.0]|         0|
|7.0|3.5| [7.0,3.5]|         0|
|8.0|4.0| [8.0,4.0]|         0|
|9.0|4.5| [9.0,4.5]|         0|
+---+---+----------+----------+
```

Comment: I read the parquet, but when i try to use VectorAssembler it gives me an error.
`val dataset = file.select("_country", "latitude", "longitude", "name").drop()    
 val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
      .setInputCols(Array("latitude", "longitude"))
      .setOutputCol("location")`


 `Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$3: (struct<latitude:double,longitude:double>) => vector)`

Comment: idk what empty .drop() is doing? try this:
`dataset = file.select("latitude", "longitude")
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
.setInputCols(dataset.columns)
.setOutputCol("location")`